# How to address minor mold problem in paint prep

Tags: bathroom, painting, mold

A little bit of localized roof leaking occurred over the winter above the bathroom.  We have addressed the roof problem, so no leaking is occurring any more, but now I'm getting ready to paint the bathroom.  One ceiling corner has a bit of mold around the corner.  How should I prepare this area before painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various mold-inhibiting primers such as [Kilz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IPUFVSS) and [Zinsser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00K7FEQPI) (links shown only as examples).

- If there is still visible stain, wash with dilute bleach and let dry.
- Apply the mold-inhibiting primer appropriate for your paint type (oil, latex, etc.).
- Paint with with your choice of material.